# Height and width of BufferedImage is null from InputStream

Tags: java, resize, inputstream, bufferedimage

I am using this method to show my `BufferedImage`:

```
public void setUriFromInpustream(InputStream in) {  
    BufferedImage bimg;
    try {
        bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
        originAspectRatio = (double) bimg.getWidth() / (double) bimg.getHeight();
        if (width == 0)
            width = bimg.getWidth();
        if (height == 0)
            height = bimg.getHeight();
        setPreserveOriginAspectRatio(preserveOriginAspectRatio);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the `bimg.getWidth()` and `bimg.getHeight()` is showing me `NullPointerException`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well documented in the ImageIO [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)):

**If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.**

Comment: I am getting the inputstream from my database is there any why to check that the data is not correpted ?

Comment: You can try writing the input stream to a file and try to open it as an image on your local machine.